# Why does my "Approve Edit" require 2 more signatories but I can edit myself with none?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

The question in question is [How to get offer details using Microsoft Partner SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37677842/how-to-get-offer-details-using-microsoft-partner-sdk)

A user has made an edit in to bring in a linked resource (good idea in case the site goes down and the image is no longer available).

If I had made the edit myself, it would have been changed immediately and that would be fine but in this case, it now needs 2 more people to approve it.

Surely, if I'm trusted to change a post myself, I should also be trusted to know what I'm doing when approving someone else's change?

P.S. I'm assuming at this point when I edit something myself, it's not just a change I can see until the edit is approved by other people.

Comment: *"I should also be trusted to know what I'm doing when approving someone else's change?"* You may know what you're doing, but looking at the edit review queue, many others are not.

Comment: Mostly to cope with robo-reviewers. It takes effort to edit the post yourself and that excludes the robo mob.

Comment: Apologies for the duplicate post. I didn't spot those.

Answer (score 10):

If you're really set on approving the edit, you can just click 'Improve and edit' and make a minor improvement. That will automatically approve the suggested edit and remove it from the review process.

There are more than a few people just racing through the review queue and approving everything that is not obviously <s>spam</s> an audit, so it's good to have at least three people reviewing the suggested edit. Such people will never take the time to *improve* a suggested edit.

Comment: Ah, that would explain it. Thanks for the response.

Comment: These people are actually approving spam, they just have a tool to auto-pass audits nowadays.

Comment: An exception should be made if you initiated the approval from the question page itself and not from the queue. I've been held up waiting on dozens of occasions and making a trivial change seems like stealing credit from the person who actually did the work.